# Are the digits of $\log 2$ and $\log 3$, or $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$, or $e$ and $\pi$, cross-correlated?

Tags: number-theory, statistics, number-systems, pattern-recognition

I try to find sequences of digits (in base $b$, with $b$ not necessarily an integer) that are not cross-correlated. While the digits in base $b$ of (say) $\pi$ and $e$ do not exhibit auto-correlations when taken separately (assuming $b$ is an integer) since these numbers are believed to be [normal numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalNumber.html), what about cross-correlations between these two sequences of digits?

The context is a business application: a generic number guessing game played with real money. If I use sequences that are cross-correlated, the player can leverage this fact (if she discovers the auto-correlations) to increase her odds of winning, making the game unfair to the operator. In short, I could lose money. For details, see section 4 in my article [Some Fun with Gentle Chaos, the Golden Ratio, and Stochastic Number Theory](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/some-fun-with-the-golden-ratio-time-series-and-number-theory).

For those interested, the picture below shows the lag-1 auto-correlation of digits in base $b$ for normal numbers such as $\pi, e, \sqrt{2}, \log 2$ and so on. The auto-correlation is zero if and only if $b$ is an integer, but it is as low as $(-3 + \sqrt{5})/2$ (this is the global minimum) when $b=(1+\sqrt{5})/2$. Interestingly, the lag-$k$ auto-correlation in base $b$ is equal to the lag-1 auto-correlation in base $b^k$.

[image]

Comment: Write more carefully: the digits of $\pi$ and $e$ do not *appear* to exhibit auto-correlations.  There is no real proof that they don't.  And why would you think the digits of $\pi$ and $e$ together might exhibit cross-correlations? They almost certainly have absolutely nothing to do with each other (the exponential relation $e^{i\pi} = -1$ using $i$ should not have any bearing on the digits of $\pi$ and $e$.)

Comment: @KCd Yes, I have spent years trying to prove that the auto-correlation is zero, to non-avail so far. I even offered \$500,000 to anyone who can prove or disprove this fact, and will probably offer this award again in the future. And I strongly believe that the cross-correlations are also zero, but it is just a belief (backed by some computations).

Comment: Someone once said here or on MathOverflow that a feature of many very hard problems is that they state exactly what you expect to be true anyway (Goldbach's conjecture, irrationality of Euler's constant .577..., etc.). The lack of digit correlation patterns that you mention is of the same type.